# Rendering related items of a Dexterity content type

Tags: templates, plone, dexterity

I have a Dexterity-based content type with the IRelatedItems behavior enabled using:

```
<property name="behaviors">
  <element value="plone.app.relationfield.behavior.IRelatedItems" />
</property>
```

I want to render the list of related items on my template but I don't know how to do it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it: first the custom view has to be a [display form](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/custom-views/display-forms), so it must derive from plone.directives.dexterity.DisplayForm:

```
class MyCustomView(dexterity.DisplayForm):
    grok.context(IMyContentType)
    grok.require('zope2.View')
```

Then you can use something like this on your page template:

```
<fieldset id="related-items" tal:condition="context/relatedItems">
    <legend i18n:translate="">Related items</legend>
    <tal:relateditems tal:content="structure view/w/IRelatedItems.relatedItems/render" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't [this](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/references) what you are looking for?

Comment: Almost; the documentation is not updated and it doesn't explain how to use the widget in a template.

Comment: You would better have summarized the contents of your link (as per StackOverflow 'styleguide'). Like many other plone.org-links, this one is dead.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using the standard dexterity relation behaviour:

plone.app.dexterity.related.IRelatedItems

With this behaviour, related items automatically appear in the content's standard view.

Giacomo

Comment: That behavior is deprecated in plone.app.dexterity since v1.0.1; you have to use the one in plone.app.relationfield. Also I need to use my own view, not the standard one.